# Transition from /p/ to /v/

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics

I would like to know how /v/ is pronounced when it comes after /p/.
**For example:** upvote

My lips come close to each other in order to produce /p/ and after the puff of air from my mouth, it becomes harder to produce /v/.

Could you please tell me how you produce /v/ after /p/?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the "puff of air" on /p/. You are effectively pronouncing the *up-* of *upvote* as a separate word — and, indeed, clearly enunciating it as a separate word.

When /p/ is followed by another consonant, such as *upvote, update* and maybe even *upholster,* the /p/ is not actually a plosive; it's a stop. That is, there is no "puff of air". Even if you have to reorganise and reposition parts of the mouth between /p/ and the following consonant, don't release air.

Try it slowly: say *up* but stop when the lips come together; hold your breath and then say *vote* (or *date,* or whatever). With practice you can run that together. But even without speaking at speed, you are not "finishing" the /p/ sound as a distinct plosive, so it will be obvious that *up-* is connected to *-vote.* (It **will** sound like you have a stammer, so making the stop as short as possible is a good thing.)

Comment: "Plosive" and "stop" are more or less synonyms (the difference in meaning, if there is any, tends to be based around whether nasals like /m/ and /n/ are included or excluded). Aspirated plosives/stops are pronounced with a "puff of air" and unaspirated (or tenuis) plosives/stops are pronounced without a puff of air.